# flutter cannot acces a method of another class using static access

Tags: flutter

title basically explains the error method i'm recieving. sorry for the huge code, but i'm basically just trying to make a call to onboarding to flip the page when a user touches the "next" text. (onTap:() => _OnboardingState.jumpForward())"
how can i do this?

i've tried using streams (i'm pretty bad with it) and maybe a solution would be bloc related. idk. i'm sure it's a pretty easy fix

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../styling/canvas.dart';
import '../../styling/theme.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingState createState() => _OnboardingState();
}

class _OnboardingState extends State<Onboarding> {
    PageController onboardingController;
    void jumpForward() async {
    onboardingController.nextPage(
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200)
    );
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: onboardingController,
      pageSnapping: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        OnboardingPage(viewModel:pages[0]),
        OnboardingPage(viewModel:pages[1]),
        OnboardingPage(viewModel:pages[2]),
      ]
    );
  }

  // jumpTo() {
  //   hello.jump
  // }
}

class PageViewModel{
  PageViewModel({
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.id,
  });

  final String title;
  final String description;
  final int id;
}

final pages = [
  PageViewModel(
    title: "Trade smart",
    description:
        "Filter stocks by metrics like short interest and short interest change.",
    id: 1,
  ),
  PageViewModel(
    title: "Connect",
    description:
        "Filter stocks by metrics like short interest and short interest change.",
    id: 2,
  ),
  PageViewModel(
    title: "Get an edge",
    description:
        "View legal insider trades filed with the SEC, made by top executives.",
    id: 3,
  ),
];

class OnboardingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  OnboardingPage({this.viewModel});

  final PageViewModel viewModel;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double _circleHeight = .022 * _height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: lightTheme.backgroundColor,
        height: _height,
        width: _width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, .1 * _height, 0.0, .1 * _height),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    .044 * _width, 0.0, .044 * _width, .022 * _height),
                child: Container(
                  //illustration
                  decoration:
                      returnCanvasStyle(), //todo: change color to theme bloc
                  width: _width,
                  height: .433 * _height,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(.044 * _width, 0.0, .044 * _width, 0.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: returnCanvasStyle(),
                  width: _width,
                  height: .344 * _height, //todo: change height
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.022 * _width,
                            0.022 * _height, 0.022 * _width, 0.0),
                        child: Text(
                          viewModel.title,
                          style: lightTheme.primaryTextTheme.display1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.044 * _width,
                            0.022 * _height, 0.044 * _width, 0.033 * _height),
                        child: Text(
                          viewModel.description,
                          style: lightTheme.primaryTextTheme.body1,
                          softWrap: true,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                0.0, 0.0, .066 * _width, 0.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: _circleHeight,
                              height: _circleHeight,
                              //color: Colors.red,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: lightTheme.primaryColor,
                                    width: .0055 * _height,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(_circleHeight)),
                                  color: lightTheme.primaryColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                0.0, 0.0, .066 * _width, 0.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: _circleHeight,
                              height: _circleHeight,
                              //color: Colors.red,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: lightTheme.primaryColor,
                                    width: .0055 * _height,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(_circleHeight)),
                                  color: Colors.transparent),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                0.0, 0.0, .0944 * _width, 0.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: _circleHeight,
                              height: _circleHeight,
                              //color: Colors.red,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: lightTheme.primaryColor,
                                    width: .0055 * _height,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(_circleHeight)),
                                  color: Colors.transparent),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  0.0, 0.0, .119 * _width, 0.0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap:() => _OnboardingState.jumpForward(),
                                child: Text(
                                "NEXT",
                                style: lightTheme.primaryTextTheme.button,
                              )),)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it that way just use a callback for your `State` method. You are trying to access a non-static method in a static way, plus, you're doing it wrong because even if the method was static, you wouldn't be accessing the active `State` and controller.

So, by using a callback, you want to pass it on the constructor of your class

```
class OnboardingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  OnboardingPage({this.viewModel, this.onNextPressed});

  final PageViewModel viewModel;
  final VoidCallback onNextPressed;
  (...)
```

Call it on your **NEXT** tap

```
 GestureDetector(
                onTap:() => onNextPressed(),
                   child: Text(
                       "NEXT",
                        style: lightTheme.primaryTextTheme.button,
                         )
                 )
```

And then passing the reference when adding the `OnboardingPage` to your widget tree in your `build` method

```
OnboardingPage(viewModel:pages[0],onNextPressed: jumpForward)
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, how would i modify the jumpForward method to modify the active state and controller?

Comment: The way you already have it, by calling `onboardingController.nextPage(...)` should be enough.

Comment: ah i see, i've tried your solution and it looks like it's calling the method, but it's telling me that 'nextpage' was called on null. i don't know why it would be doing this.

Comment: Because you've not instantiated the `PageController` just add it to the `onboardingController = PageController();`

Comment: tried that and i'm getting an error "pagecontroller.page cannot be accessed before a pageview is built with it". reported here > https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20621

Comment: i tried commenting out the commands in the method and that got rid of the errror, which makes me think that the method is being called before the pageview is created. if i change it to an async method body, then it's incompatible with the OnBoardingPage. any ideas? thank you so much for you help so far

Comment: What are you commenting?

Comment: pageController.nextPage(
        curve: Curves.easeIn, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));

Comment: Do you get the exception when you press the NEXT text or before that?

Comment: i get it before i press it

Comment: just fixed it, what i did was I implemented "onNextPressed: jumpForward()" instead of "onNextPressed: jumpForward," and it was calling the function before the pageview was built. thank you for your time good sir